# How to Deploy a Java Web Service in a Private Network

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, web-services, tomcat

I was able to create a JAVA Rest API Web Service using SpringBoot. How do I deploy it so not only my localhost can access it but other computers in the private LAN as well.

I dont want to officialy publish it outside. Is Glassfish the tool for this?

I want to have an endpoint like

```
 https://privatewebservice.net/api/
```

in the private network that other people can use.

Thanks.

Comment: if you use server and you are in the same network lan with others computers, they  can access to your   `https://localhost:port/api/`  just with remplacing `localhost` by your current `ip adress`

Comment: @ZINEMahmoud just to clarify, what server are we referring to, Tomcat Server?

Comment: check my comment below @noogui

Answer (score 1):

Deploy the rest on your tomcat server on port `80` and in other PCs in the private LANs update `host` file for `privatewebservice.net` to point to your PC's IP in the LAN

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I dont want to touch other people's PC. I just want to use like an Application Server (Glassfish) in the private network and share the endpoint to the colleagues.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to run an *a* servlet container(aka web server). There are many; Jetty, Tomcat, Glassfish etc. That servlet container will start and host your application and make it available via it's port(s).

You can run this process on any physical or virtual machine that is visible on your LAN. You could even use your own machine for this if it's visible to your LAN (barring firewall/network rules blocking the traffic).

To make it available to your LAN from your machine, find your machines internal LAN IP address (run `ifconfig` on Linux or `ipconfig` on Windows) and try accessing the app via that IP from your browser. If other machines on your LAN can see your machine, they should be able to access it too via that IP address (likely you will also have an internal DNS name for your machine which would be cleaner to use in case your IP address changes).

Obviously that's only good for development and testing. Generally for internal hosted applications for your company you would have a machine running somewhere that you could deploy the app to to make it accessible by others on your LAN.

It's worth noting that Spring Boot by default comes with an embedded server/servlet container. By default this is Tomcat, but can be changed to say Jetty, via configuration and changing default dependencies in your maven POM file or Gradle build file. The default will be fine unless you have some specific reason to change it.

To use this embedded server, use one of either Maven or [Gradle Spring Boot plugins](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.springframework.boot) which will provide a set of tasks that can be used to build an executable Java `jar` file for the application that will run the application on the embedded server, and the application within it. This can then be run with something like `java -jar myapp.jar`

Technically speaking this would probably be the easiest way to deploy the application. With the only major requirement on the machine you are deploying to being a compatible version of Java. Although I'd recommend wrapping that app in a Docker image that already has Java on it and use Docker to run the docker image as a container. This means your applications' dependencies(including Java and it's specific version) are housed within the docker image/container and also means the machine that will run the app could host many different applications resource efficiently(RAM, CPU etc), with each managing their own dependencies. The machine hosting the app would then just need Docker installed on it, and doesn't get polluted with any other applications dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

follow this step :

1- generate a war file of your Spring-boot project API - [see here how to do](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/)

2- deploy it on tomcat server [see here how to do](https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-deploy-war)

3- replace your `localhost` with your `@adress ip` (where the server is on and where the project is deployed)